# Windows Service starting and stopping immidiately. Howto Debug?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, service, windows-services

I have built a windows service that is working fine when I run it in Visual Studio. I also created an Installer for the Service. Everything works fine except the starting of the service itself. It shuts itself down immidiately telling me that it has been stopped an nothing else.

How can I debug this? I think there might be some Problems with the refrences or attached DLLs I am using but I can't find away to Debug my Service.

WinDbg Preview is on option however it can only debug a running service, which I do not have.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a call to `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()` in the `Main()` function, the constructor, or the `OnStart()` callback of your service. When you start the service from the Service Control Manager (SCM), you will be presented with a dialog that allows you to start a new instance of Visual Studio or attach to an existing instance. Select the one you want (I usually select the existing instance), and the service should stop at your programmatic breakpoint. You can debug from there.

If the programmatic breakpoint isn't hit, that means one of two things. First, it could mean that the Windows service isn't starting correctly because it can't find the necessary .dll files. In this case, make sure that your Windows service is located in the same directory as the .dll files you need and/or that the necessary .dll files are located in the library path. The other problem could be that you do not have the necessary permissions on your system to debug a service (e.g., are you a local administrator on the system?). Get with your system administrator to figure out what permissions are required, make sure your account has those permissions, reboot your system, and try again.

HTH

Comment: thx. it worked when i changed Break to Launch but still it seems to break right before the app starts. I guess he is missing some references but i have no chance to find out what...

Comment: I will accept you answer as corret. Thank you very much. Me Problem was a logical on. I was having a tray menu which is not allowed in a service... So I will have to split my app or find another solution. Thank you!